# Create a HighCharts pie chart using JSON Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, highcharts, cartodb

I am trying to plot a pie chart using JSON data returned from `cartoDB SQL`.

I am using the example provided on the [High Charts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing) website but the chart is not loading. Below is my javascript code. Can you see anything wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
      },
      series: [{}]
  };

  var jsonURL = 'https://1025.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?&q=SELECT status FROM kenya_primary_schools';

  $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(data) {
    var obj = data.rows, hObj = [];
    if(obj.length){
      for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
        hObj.push([obj[i]['status']]);
      }
      console.log(hObj);
    }
    options.series[0].data = data;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  });
});
```

Comment: would you mind adding a console.log between `options.series[0].data = data` and `var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);`, and posting the output?

Comment: @RahulSharma - http://i.imgur.com/iPyExu3.png

Comment: @Pimmol from my side, everything looks fine. No error on the code

Comment: @Pimmol he is in the code, you might have made a mistake in your fiddle

Comment: In your data I see only test, not y values (numbers). Where have you that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After modifying your code to some extend, I managed to get the following result:

[image: PRIVATE VS PUBLIC PIE CHART]

**Key points you should do**

You would need to check from the Highcharts documentation on how the data object is given to series.data from the [Highcharts doc](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series%3Cpie%3E.data)

Since you have two options from the `cartoDB`: PRIVATE and PUBLIC, you should think how to store them in a array/object and how to then form the data object from the pie chart.

Hint:

*options.series[0].data = data;*

*hObj.push([obj[i]['status']]);*

Comment: This should be the final result. thanks for the tip!

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to explicitly find the solution despite the hints. :-( ..

Comment: Many thanks! I'll use it as a case study for similar cases. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors in your code. You may try correcting like this and give it another try.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'pie'
    },
   series: [{}]
},
    jsonURL = 'https://1025.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?&q=SELECT status FROM kenya_primary_schools';

$.getJSON(jsonURL, function(data) {
  var obj = data.rows,
     hObj = [],
    chart;
  if (obj.length) for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) hObj.push([obj[i].status]);
  options.series[0].data = data;
  chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
});
```